# Lost in Development

Tags: game-design, rpg, mmo, game-maker, game-industry

My name is Julian Ngolla. I am a 20 year old biology major who is a junior at Hunter college in NYC. In other words i am constantly busy and am basically broke. Ever since i was a kid me and my brother have been die hard gamers and have loved every second of it. Over the past 5 or 6 years my brother and i have been seeing something wrong in the directions some Games are going like call of duty and battlefield. Games like these usually still end up being short term fun so it's not that big of a deal.
Games like Destiny, The division, The Witcher,  and ESO on the other hand, that promise long term value and rewards based on commitment, seem to not be living up to the grandeur we so fantasize. Don't get me wrong, i have played all of these games and bought all of their DLC along with reaching max level and/or top spots on their leaderboards, and i have Loved every minute of doing so. Unfortunately once i reach a certain point in a Game, where i can't go any higher, i start to fantasize of all the things that could have been.
What if the Witcher had multiplayer, what if you could travel the stars seamlessly in Destiny, or enter every building NYC in the Division. What if ESO had hundreds more abilities, 10 more attributes and 50 more races allowing for endless build opportunities. Or my favorite what if any mmorpg these days incorporated Runescapes skill and grinding system.
(Albion Online shows promise)

Games like overwatch and battlefield
Will always be around and i can't wait for them to come out. They provide me with the short term fun and excitement that doesn't require much to be rewarded. But when it comes to my favorite games, the ones i have to put countless hours into to be rewarded, they don't seem to be doing the trick anymore.

Now the fun part.
Do to my lack of drive and commitment to recent games, i have set out on a journey to make the best one ever.
Over the past few months i have been brainstorming a game idea that would combine the most popular genres all into one. It's part Mmorpg, part Fps/Tps, and part Moba.
My main inspiration Comes from Dota 2 and League of Legends, where either win or lose i would still be upset that my time with whatever character i was playing (Mostly shaco) has to come to an end.
I mean, just imagine playing an rpg as Lissandra or Dragon Knight then switching over to pvp to kick some ass with them. Win or lose you can still go back to mmo mode and evolve and Progress as a character.
Pretty sick right?!

So... As of now i have over 1000 pages of Lore, 1000 pages of character information containing the weapons and abilities of over 80 unique characters split into 4 warring factions, and I have the character models of each hero imprinted in my head.
I have over 700 pages of gathering and crafting mechanics which includes a skilling system for both combat and non combat skills ( similar to runescape).

To some it all up, and dumb it all down,
On a few thousand pieces of paper, i have created a game that is basically an mmorpg version of league of legends where you advance your character by leveling up a multitude of skills that define your role and play style.

So the main question i have for you all at the moment is...
What Next?

Comment: Not even considering that the scale of your ambitions is absolutely unreasonable for a first project, you're effectively asking a "How do I start?" question, and a primarily opinion based question at the same time.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour

Quote: "Don't ask about... Questions that are primarily opinion-based. Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer."

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Quote: "and it is not about...

How to get started making a game.
What language/engine/SDK you should learn.
Etc..."

Comment: see also: "duplicate", "unclear what you're asking", and "too broad"... If you haven't read the basic instructions for using this site, how are we supposed to have confidence that you'll google all the other stuff you will need to later?

Answer (score 9):

The next step would be to secure a budget of several million dollar to hire a team of a few hundred experienced people, because that's what it would take to create the greatest game ever. Do you have several million dollar laying around? Or do you know any publishers who would trust you with a million dollar budget because you have a solid track record of executing several large game development projects successfully? No? Well, then I guess [your game idea is too big](http://www.yourgameideaistoobig.com/).

When you have no experience with game development and no budget to spend, then I would recommend you to start small. Very small. Pick a very tiny subset of your concepts, learn some game development tools, and try to turn it into reality.

See how it turns out, have people testplay it, discard what the testplayers don't like and build on what they like. When you have a prototype of a game, think about how to acquire funding for hiring people to help you develop on the idea and turn it into a product you can sell.

Your first marketable product will still just be a tiny glimpse of your huge pile of concepts and far, far away from being "the greatest game ever". But getting it to market will not just get you the funding you need for your next game, it will also give you the game development experience to tell which parts of your concepts will not work out in practice anyway.